# How to send firebase quota data to web app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a web app and would like to know if there's a way to link the quota data provided by the firebase console to the web app as shown in the figure below.
[image]
This way an administrator can log into the web app and get some information about the database without logging into the console.

Some research has led me to BigQuery, Google Data Studio and Google Analytics but I'm not sure how to directly link that with a page on my web app. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to read how much quota your project has used. If you want to display such information, you'll have to store it yourself.

Comment: I think it's simple to manually get that info for things like the number of user accounts or the total space of all uploaded files but do you have a suggestion as to how I can manually count database reads and writes?

Comment: You would essentially start logging those from your application code. It's not ideal, but I don't see an alternative way to get this done right now.